# How I can solve this differential equation ( i did transformed to u for make simply, then how i can do solve?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I transformed to du/dx - u/x = -x. then next how i can solve..? can you give any hint? original equation was this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0vg4.png)

Comment: Multiply both sides by $x^{-1}$.

Comment: @Tavish  Really thank you!!! i got u =1/2 x^2. then...how I can solve next?

Comment: What did you put $u$ as? Just substitute for $u$.

Comment: @math Thank you to reply! I got integrate factor is 1/x, so i multiplied all side,  so(1/x)(du/dx) - (1/x^2)u = 1/2,  so integrated and got u/x  = x/2...am i wrong,,,?

Comment: I hope to give recommend on your all comment but i dont know why i cant press

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we start from the equation :

$\frac{(x^2 + 2y^2)dx}{dy} = xy$.

We choose $u = x^2 + 2y^2$, so that we get :

$4\frac{dx}{du}u=x$ so $4\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{u}$

So $4\ln x = \ln u +c$.

So $x^4 = c.u$

So $x^2 +2y^2 = x^4/c$.

So $y=\pm \sqrt{x^4/2c - x^2/2}.$
So $y = \pm x \sqrt{-1 + c_1 x^2}$.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Really really thank you! but I am wondering how i can from u= x^2 + 2y^2 to 4(dx/du) * u = x..? thank you. I can understand other!! from you.

Comment: I hope to vote 1 but I am really sad i cant vote you right now

Comment: I solved!!! THank you.!! and understood all.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{du}{dx} -\frac{u}{x} = -x$

By multiplying both sides by $1/x$, we get :

$\frac{1}{x} \frac{du}{dx} -\frac{u}{x^2}=-1$

Then we remark that $\frac{d(u/x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{x} \frac{du}{dx} - \frac{u}{x^2}$

So we get that $\frac{d(u/x)}{dx} = -1$.

We integrate : $\frac{u}{x} = -x+a$ for some $a$.

So $u(x) = -\frac{x^2}{2} +a x +c$ for some $c$.

Comment: Thank you much!! From you i realized i get mistake from before. Love you.

Comment: @ Umm I cant understand about next stage even i seeing book...can you help me more..?

Comment: The image you linked is partial. I can't see the variable change you made to get the equation with $u$.

Comment: I edited my problem, and i setted y =u ^2, maybe i had mistake from before. so edited to du/dx - u/x = x/(2u^3) ..I am really first time to solve this. can you do solve and let me understand me? in photo, there has answer. and...when x=-1, y= 1

Comment: I tried solve..but there has 4order equation.. what is the problem..?